# comparing two unix time files to delete old files

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am using the below bit of code to get the `timestamps` of files on my cloud server and then delete any that are over a certain age.

For now the code is set to delete anything older than 10 minutes for testing.

However it deletes everything, even if I upload some files then run the script 10 seconds later.

Is there some small problem I am not seeing?

```
    $auth->authenticate();

    //connect
    $conn = new CF_Connection($auth);

    //create a handle for the CLOUD FILES container we want to delete from
    $daily_dose = $conn->get_container('daily_dose');

    //delete the obeject 
    $daily_packages = $daily_dose->list_objects();
    //print_r($daily_packages);
    //$public_container = $conn->get_container("public");   

    //$file_age = 86400; // 1 day in seconds
    $file_age = 600; // 10 minutes

    echo 'current time: ';
    echo $current_time = time();
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'time offset: ';
    echo $previous_day = $current_time - $file_age;
    echo '<br>';

    foreach($daily_packages as $package)
    {   
        echo $item = $daily_dose->get_object($package);
        $modified = $item->last_modified;
        echo ' ' . $modified;
        echo ' -> ' . strtotime($modified);
        echo '<br>';

        //If the modified time of the file is less the current time - 1 day in seconds (older than 1 day) delete it
        if ( $modified < $previous_day )
        {
            //delete the file
            $daily_dose->delete_object($item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also include what is `echo`'d from that, it'd be useful for us too.

Comment: What exactly is in `$item->last_modified`? Is it, in fact, a timestamp of the same sort as `time()` returns? Suppose you instrument your code a little more: `echo ' ' . $modified . ' -> ' . strtotime($modified) . '; comparing ' . $modified . ' with ' . $previous_day . ' => ' . ($modified < $previous_day) . <br>;` or something of the kind; is the output illuminating?

Comment: `last_modified` is a class variable that will return something like `Sun, 20 Mar 2011 23:09:36 GMT` which i then turn into a `timestamps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling strtotime() on $modified, I guess it is not a UNIX timestamp already.
time() does return a UNIX timestamp.

Shouldn't the check, then, be as follows:

```
if(strtotime($modified) < $previous_day)
```

That way you are comparing UNIX timestamps and, given that $item->last_modified returns the correct value, your code should work.

If not, make sure there are no time or timezone differences between what time() returns, and the software setting the last_modified value on your $items (easy to check with some debug output)

Comment: In your comment on your own question you indicate that 'last_modified is a class variable that will return something like Sun, 20 Mar 2011 23:09:36 GMT' so I am certain that you will have to change your 'if' condition now. But making sure there are no timezone difference is always good :)

Comment: Thanks Will, it was both. I was just outputting the `$modified` `timestamp` not putting it into a variable and comparing it AND my cloud server is on LONDON time and my PHP server is on DENVER time, works perfect now!